# Send datasources in javascript to mySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I made this code inside script to save datasource event in database but nothing happens, no values are saved in the database:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{id:event.id, name:event.name, startDate:event.startDate, endDate:event.endDate},
    success:function(){
        alert("Added Successfully");
    }
})
```

file insert.php:

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recuperation', 'root', '');
$query = "INSERT INTO events (id, name, startDate, endDate) VALUES (:id, :name, :startDate, :endDate)";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute( array(':id'  => $_POST['event.id'], ':name'  => $_POST['event.name'], ':startDate' => $_POST['event.startDate'],':endDate' => $_POST['event.endDate']));

?>
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Do you get the right values posted into the php script?

Comment: You use for example $_POST['event.id'], you have to use $_POST['id'] etc. in your php file.

Comment: thanks to you brothers  i did it tonight and it's working good

Comment: now my brother the big probleme is with how to display it , from database to datasources

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the posted values as you named your json object:

```
{
    id: event.id,
    name: event.name,
    startDate: event.startDate,
    endDate: event.endDate
}
```

So your post values will be in those keys: `id`, `name`, etc.. E.g. change `$_POST['event.name']` to `$_POST['name']`. Try this:

```
$statement->execute( array(':id'  => $_POST['id'], ':name'  => $_POST['name'], ':startDate' => $_POST['startDate'],':endDate' => $_POST['endDate']));
```

Comment: now my brother the big probleme is with how to display it , from database to datasources

Comment: @merradiyounes ok, but that should be another question. If this problem is solved you have to finish your question by accepting the answer.